# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, angular10

I've been trying to subscribe to a particular observable(i am a beginner to rxjs), but I keep failing.
here is my code

---

**here I need to assign the first element of usergroups array element to this.currentGroup**

```
const selectedUserGroups$ =
this.userGroupsService.getUserGroupsWithUsers(this.selectedUserGroupIds).pipe(shareReplay());

this.selectedUserGroups$.subscribe( (usergroups: UserGroup[]) =>
this.currentGroup = usergroups[0]); 

if(this.currentGroup.users?.length >0) 
{
  this.showUsersList(); 
}
```

but this won't work as i expected, Appreciate your help regarding this

Comment: Your edition is pretty much a separate question, but: the `if(this.currentGroup.users?.length >0)` chunk should be under the `subscribe`, after the `this.currentGroup =` assignment, otherwise it'll run too early. And for further reading, here's an evergreen SO classic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const selectedUserGroups$ = // assignment here
this.selectedUserGroups$.subscribe( //...
```

Those are two different objects: the variable in the function scope `selectedUserGroups$` and the object property `this.selectedUserGroups$`.

Remove `this.` from the second line, for example. Or replace `const selectedUserGroups$ =`  with `this.selectedUserGroups$ =`.

Comment: Thanks that solves my problem partially but unfortunately I do have another problem, it does not wait until this.currentGroup get values. As per my understanding, it's not working the asynchronous way. it's executing lines below without waiting to assign values for this.currentGroup

Comment: FYI I have edited the posted code hereafter I changed this const selectedUserGroups$ to this.selectedUserGroups$ it's partially solved. asi saied above comment, now it's executing the if statement without waiting for this.currentGroup assigned it's values :-(